# problem regarding text mode in latexdraw

Tags: graphics, editors

I am new to Latex. I am using LaTeXdraw to draw figures. However when I try to write the text in Text mode it is not getting converted into the desired form as it happens in Latex. I am attaching a snapshot for your reference. Any help regarding this is greatly appreciated. [image]

Comment: have you configured the editor to tell it where the latex binary is as described here? https://github.com/arnobl/latexdraw/wiki/Manual#latex-text-rendering

Comment: Yeah i have done that, but the problem still persists